# How to check my PHP and MySQL version on Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, command-line-interface

HI I am going to install MyBB but I am not sure whether I have installed the correct version of PHP and MySQL.

> PHP version 5.1.0 or above with XML Extension installed
>
> MySQL version 4.0 or above

How to check that? Especiall the PHP XML Extension?

Is there simpler way than the `<?php phpinfo() ?>` solution? I am expecting a command line solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Do it from your command line:

```
php -v
mysql -V
```

and:

```
php -i | grep -i '^libxml'
```

OR

Put this in your root directory:

```
 <?php
    phpinfo();
 php?>
```

Save it as phpinfo.php and point your browser to it (this could be http://localhost/phpinfo.php)

Comment: Using `mysql -V` can return with unexpected errors due to permissions.

Answer (score 10):

Use `dpkg` to find the installed package versions.

```
dpkg -l | grep '\(php\|mysql\)'
```

Comment: Returns nothing if compile from source.

Answer (score 3):

Any one of these queries will tell you what the MySQL version running is once connected:

```
SELECT VERSION();

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
```

This works for MySQL 5.1+

```
SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name='version';
```

Doing the following from the command line:

mysql -V will get you the version of the client.

mysqld -V  will get you the version of the server.

Comment: ERROR 3167 (HY000): The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES' feature is disabled; see the documentation for 'show_compatibility_56'